# Angular How to escape string to build HTML myself to interpret: as HTML tags i added and as escaped data strings

Tags: html, angular

I have array of strings that i want to show in DIV as ad-hoc builded html list with adding of BRs or some additional formatting.
Strings are data-strings so i want to escape them to prevent interpretation as HTML.

Eg. for array `{"First Element", "<p>Second Element</p>"}` and creating inner html like:
`escape(arr[0])+"<br>"+escape(arr[1])`
I'd like to see it separated with line break but with paragraphs tags just shown in visible text.

What I found in Angular there is sanitization that may make potential XSS "safe". But i want to force data string to be shown, and not interpreted in "safe form".

Comment: You can do something like using the Domsanitizer to create unsafeHtml and then bind that in the template with innerHtml `this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<div style="border: 1px solid red;"><h2>Safe Html</h2><span>{{ unsafeHtml }}</span></div>');` This will create an unsafe html string that you can pass the template like this`<div [innerHTML]="safeHtml"></div>`